# Ethernet cable is broken or not properly plugged. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, internet-connection, windows-error-reporting

This morning I tried to install Ubuntu 15.0.4 (having already Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bits installed). I did a dual partition and it worked perfectly. I installed some apps on Ubuntu for programming and Internet connection was perfectly working. 
A few hours later I entered Windows 7 and Internet was not working. I entered Ubuntu 15.0.4 and it was going perfect.
I decided to format and delete the two partitions (doing a backup before), and install another time Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bits alone.
I did it successfully, I formatted and installed that Operative System. I used PdaNet+ (for tethering by usb the wifi from the android to pc) to have Internet and install drivers using Diver Booster 3 (never caused me any problem). I installed all the drivers that the app said that were needed or obsolet. I keep having the same error: "Ethernet cable is broken or not properly plugged".
I tried changing the ethernet cable, but didn't work.
I'd apprecciate some help, and sorry for my English.

Comment: Go get the driver for the NIC directly from the manufacturer and try that one. What is the actual make/model of your NIC?  Does it show up in the right area of the Device Manager, without and exclamation marks or errors?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Already tried. It is shown without exclamation marks or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shutting down the computer for a minute before booting into Windows. There is a "residual state" in some peripherals which persists upon rebooting and makes drivers misbehave. Only solution in that case is to shutdown the power totally to clear the device's internal temp memory.

Comment: Ohhhhh my GOD, U WERE RIGHT